# prove that the finite group G has a fixed point in S if |G|=$p^r$, p prime, |S|=N, (p,N)=1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am asked to solve the following

Let G be a finite group with $p^r$ elements, where p is prime. if G acts on the finite set S with N elements and $(p,N)=1$, prove that there exists $s\in S$ such that $g*s=s,\forall g\in G$

I am able to get that $\sum_{g\in G}I(g)>0$ but I don't see how to convert that into $I(g)>0, \forall g\in G$

Comment: Hint: The cardinality of an orbit must divide the cardinality of the group, and $S$ is the disjoint union of the orbits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G_{s}$ and $O_{s}$ be the stabilizer and orbit of an element $s \in S$.
Then $p^{r} = |G| = |G_{s}||O_{s}|$, Hence $|O_{s}| = p^{k}$.

On another hand we number the orbits that make up $S$ arbitrarily, as $O_{1}, ..., O_{k}$. Then $|S| = \sum_{i=1}^{k}|O_{i}|$ with $|O_{i}| = p^{e_{i}}$. If $e_{i} \geq 1$ for all $i$, then we get that $p$ divide $|S|$, which contradicts the hypothesis. Hence $e^{j} = 0$ for some $j$, so that $|O_{j}| = 1$, but this implies the result and we are done as it was promised.